# How does `traceur-compiler` work to convert ES-next to ES-present

Tags: ecmascript-6, porting, ecmascript-5, traceur

I googled to find any existing ES-6 to ES-5 transpiler. There I found [traceur-compiler](https://github.com/google/traceur-compiler/wiki/Getting-Started). I just tried it by embedding on a page and found it working fine.

Then I was curious to understand that how the `traceur-compiler` actually work under the hood. Then I went to understand the source code of the library which was taking me quite long time to understand the internal implementation of the library.

I believe for understanding the working of `traceur-compiler` if I get some tool or some mechanism which shows the equivalent ES-5 output for some of the sample input of ES-6 script. It would be a lot easier for me to understand the working.

For example let's say following is sample ES-6 code

```
      class Greeter {
        constructor(message) {
          this.message = message;
        }
        greet() {
          console.info(this.message); // 'Hello, world!'
        }
      };
      var greeter = new Greeter('Hello, world!');
      greeter.greet();
```

I would like to know the ES-5 equivalent of the above code.

Any idea if there is debugging mode of traceur-compiler or some other tool facilitating me the same.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you want to know / the issue is. Could you elaborate on your question please?

Comment: @FelixKling Please check the question again.. I have updated it.. Please let me know if you can understand it now.

Comment: So, In essence, you are asking for us to refer you to an off site resource that can explain to you how traceur works?

Comment: Why don't you just run traceur and have a look at the result? I don't see the problem here.

Comment: It can be any offsite resource OR it can be some debug mode of this transpiler OR it can be some other transpiler which gives me an insight about how the conversion between ES-6 script to ES-5 is happening?

Comment: @Felix: Running the traceur did not let me see its converted output even in the browser. It just worked and the console came but I was not able to find any updated/replaced scripts in the firebug/developer tools.

Comment: Run it from the console as explained by Thomas in his answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just invoke the compiler on the command line. [Here are instructions](https://github.com/google/traceur-compiler/wiki/Compiling-Offline):

```
$ ./traceur --out out/greeter.js --script greeter.js
```

Comment: is there any installation for `traceur` which makes the above command run. Currently it is not recognized as an internal or external program.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use their online transcoding demo to get a quick of what ES5 gets generated. I made a simple class and got to see the generated JS here:

http://google.github.io/traceur-compiler/demo/repl.html#class%20Foo%20%7B%0A%20%20constructor()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20this.bar%20%3D%20%22yay%22%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0A%0A%20%20

(Try http://google.github.io/traceur-compiler/demo/repl.html if the above link stops working).

Comment: nice... should be good to check the generated equivalent in ES5. Thanks :-)